# I am using react-native 0.57, is there anyway to get UID/tag id of a NFC tag on ios

Tags: ios, react-native, nfc

I am using react-native-nfc-manager. But the uid or id of NFC tag is coming as undefined for ios.
On android it works very well.

Comment: Were you able to get the UID of NFC in iOS ?